# Sum values in a column based on two criteria

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, sum

I have this dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2000-01','2000-01', '2000-01','2000-02','2000-03', '2000-03', '2099-01'],
    'Value': [10, 30, 2, 3, 40, 50, 999],
    'Name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Jessica','Jessica', 'Will', 'Will', 'Peter']
    })


      Date  Value     Name
0  2000-01     10    Peter
1  2000-01     30    Peter
2  2000-01      2  Jessica
3  2000-02      3  Jessica
4  2000-02     40     Will
5  2000-03     50     Will
6  2099-01    999    Peter
```

I want to sum the values from `Value` based on `Date` and `Name` such that the results will be below. Here you can see that for `Peter` and dates `2000-01`, there are two values of `10` and `30`, where the sum is `40`, such that it is added in the first row of `Sum`. In contrast, `Jessica` only have one value per month (as can be seen in `2000-01` and `2000-02` with values `2` and `3`), such that those two rows will not be summed.

```
      Date  Value     Name  Sum
0  2000-01     10    Peter   40
1  2000-01     30    Peter   40
2  2000-01      2  Jessica    2
3  2000-02      3  Jessica    3
4  2000-02     40     Will   40
5  2000-03     50     Will   50
6  2099-01    999    Peter  999
```

How can I sum values based on two criteria as seen above? I only know of `pd.pivot_table()`, but that will add new columns to the right based on unique values in a column rather downwards.

Comment: @jezrael Oh, yes. My mistake. I will fix it now.

Comment: `data["Sum"] = data.groupby(["Date", "Name"]).transform('sum')` ?

Comment: Need `data["Sum"] = data.groupby(["Date", "Name"])['Value'].transform('sum')`